# how to loop over array of objects and get values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please read fully. Do not mark it duplicate until you really find it. I have an array of objects like below.

```
const filterParams = [
      { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Cove' },
      { 'area[]': 'Applehead Island' },
      { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Channel' },
      { 'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water' },
      { baths: '0 - 14' },
      { price: '0.00 - 9,876,100.00' }
    ];
```

I need to loop over this and add this to form data. I'm doing like below.

```
filterParams.map(param => {
      return formData.append(param.key, param.value);
    });
```

Expected:  param.key is waterfront_type[] and param.value is Cove. so internally it should be `formData.append('waterfront_type[]', 'Cove');`

Getting: both undefined. `formData.append(undefined, undefined);`

Comment: `Expected: param.key is waterfront_type[]` [why would you expect that?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: And why are you using `.map` at all, if all you want is to loop through the array?

Comment: Try using formData.append(Object.keys(param)[0], Object.values(param)[0])

Comment: @user3743266 I don't think that's doing what you think it would be doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to get the key, and the value.

**Note:** the default `= []` handles the case of empty objects.

```
filterParams.map(param => {
  const [[key, value] = []] = Object.entries(param);
  return formData.append(key, value);
});
```

If you just need to call `formData(key, value)`, and you don't care about the returned values (if any), use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
filterParams.forEach(param => {
  const [[key, value] = []] = Object.entries(param);
  formData.append(key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`param` variable passed to `.map` function is a javascript object and you cannot access its keys by using just `object.key`. Instead do:

```
filterParams.map(param => {
   var keys = Object.keys(param);
   return formData.append(keys[0], param[keys[0]]);
});
```

Here, we are getting all the keys of the `param` object and get the first (0th index) as the key you require (assuming that your array have objects with one key).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to put all dictionary entrySet into a FormData:

```
filterParams.forEach(param => {
    Object.keys(param).forEach(function(key) {
         let value = param[key];
         formData.append(key, value);
    });      
});
```

It will produce the output of:

```
["waterfront_type%5B%5D=Cove",
 "area%5B%5D=Applehead%20Island",
 "waterfront_type%5B%5D=Channel",
 "waterfront_type%5B%5D=Open%20Water",
 "baths=0%20-%2014",
 "price=0.00%20-%209%2C876%2C100.00"]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use javascript filters

```
 filterParams = filterParams.filter(function(itm){
   Object.keys(itm).forEach(function(key, value){
     return formData.append(key, value);
   })
 })
```

Comment: Why use `.filter` if all you want is to loop through the array?

Comment: looping through the array or using javascript filters i think both should be the same. anyhow you have iterate through that array that does not matter if you are using filter, map or simple loop iteration. iteration complexity would be the same. Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't matter, why are there different methods - `.filter`, `.map`, `.forEach`, `.some`, `.every`, `.find`? There would surely need to be a single one if they just go through the array.

Comment: in any PL array iteration is done in O(n) time only. the difference lies in the way we are picking up (search through the element ) that could be in (binary search way, a tree form or a hashing way) in this case search can take O(logn) time or O(1) time but all these works on sorted array, since array of object, are not sorted and to make it sorted you again need quicksort or some other methodologies  that itself take O(nlogn) or O(n) time. hence definitely you need to iterate through the array in every possible way whether you are using (filter, map or forEach...etc). i hope you are clear.

Comment: But you are *specifically* suggesting `.filter`. Why? What's the advantage over any other method? And are you aware of why are there different ones?

Comment: i am not _specifically_ suggesting `.filter` method. other already used different methods. I thought to give it a try with `.filter`

Comment: In that case you are making a bad suggestion. Each of the array iteration methods has *a purpose*. With `.filter` the idea is to take an array *pass a predicate* and get a new array in the end by testing each item. OP is already wrong with using `.map` which is used to *apply morphism to each item* and produce a new array out of it. You should be using `.forEach` because it has no such extra things. Both `.map` and `.filter` will produce an extra array that will need to be GC-ed, `.filter` will also do the extra testing of each item. Most of all, it matters for code clarity.

Comment: yes, agree with your point of "return the new array" and the GC things. thanks for the js underhood chat.